# How to use Facemarker in EMGUCV?

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I'm trying to follow [this OpenCV tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d7/dec/tutorial_facemark_usage.html) but I have not managed to create the FaceInvoke.FaceDetectNative function, I tried to use this function but the application stops working.

```
static bool MyDetector(IntPtr input, IntPtr output)
    {
        CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier(@"..\..\Resource\EMGUCV\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");
        Image<Gray, byte> grayImage = (new Image<Bgr, byte>(CvInvoke.cvGetSize(input))).Convert<Gray, byte>();
        grayImage._EqualizeHist();
        Rectangle[] faces = faceDetector.DetectMultiScale(grayImage, 1.1, 10, Size.Empty);
        VectorOfRect rects = new VectorOfRect(faces);
        CvInvoke.cvCopy(rects.Ptr, output, IntPtr.Zero);
        return true;
    }
```

On the other hand I tried calling the GetFaces method by passing a Mat object = new Mat (); as IOutputArray which also has not worked (Crash error).

```
FacemarkLBFParams fParams = new FacemarkLBFParams();
        fParams.ModelFile = @"..\..\Resource\EMGUCV\facemarkmodel.yaml";
        FacemarkLBF facemark = new FacemarkLBF(fParams);
        facemark.SetFaceDetector(MyDetector);

        VectorOfRect result = new VectorOfRect();
        Image<Bgr, Byte> image = new Image<Bgr, byte>(@"C:\Users\matias\Documents\Proyectos\100-20.bmp");
        bool success = facemark.GetFaces(image, result);

        Rectangle[] faces = result.ToArray();
```

Thank's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several hours I have managed to detect the points of a face, for that use the Fit method, which receives the image, the faces (such as VectorOfRect) and a VectorOfVectorOfPointF for the output

```
public Image<Bgr, Byte> GetFacePoints()
    {
        CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier(@"..\..\Resource\EMGUCV\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");
        FacemarkLBFParams fParams = new FacemarkLBFParams();
        fParams.ModelFile = @"..\..\Resource\EMGUCV\lbfmodel.yaml";
        fParams.NLandmarks = 68; // number of landmark points
        fParams.InitShapeN = 10; // number of multiplier for make data augmentation
        fParams.StagesN = 5; // amount of refinement stages
        fParams.TreeN = 6; // number of tree in the model for each landmark point
        fParams.TreeDepth = 5; //he depth of decision tree
        FacemarkLBF facemark = new FacemarkLBF(fParams);
        //facemark.SetFaceDetector(MyDetector);

        Image<Bgr, Byte> image = new Image<Bgr, byte>(@"C:\Users\matias\Downloads\personas-buena-vibra-caracteristicas-1200x600.jpg");
        Image<Gray, byte> grayImage = image.Convert<Gray, byte>();
        grayImage._EqualizeHist();

        VectorOfRect faces = new VectorOfRect(faceDetector.DetectMultiScale(grayImage));
        VectorOfVectorOfPointF landmarks = new VectorOfVectorOfPointF();
        facemark.LoadModel(fParams.ModelFile);

        bool success = facemark.Fit(grayImage, faces, landmarks);
        if (success)
        {
            Rectangle[] facesRect = faces.ToArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < facesRect.Length; i++)
            {
                image.Draw(facesRect[i], new Bgr(Color.Blue), 2);
                FaceInvoke.DrawFacemarks(image, landmarks[i], new Bgr(Color.Blue).MCvScalar);
            }
            return image;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Now all that remains is to optimize the code and continue with my project